# Prove a set of lines through one point is convex and bounded

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I am working on the proof that the following set is convex and bounded $$S= \{M_{a}|a \in (0,1)\},$$ where
$$M_{a}=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2_{++}: ax+(1-a)y=b, \text{ and } b \text{ is a fixed positive real number}\}.$$
Intuitively, $S$ is a set of lines on the $xy$-plane passing through the same point $(b,b)$ and is the subset of $\mathbb{R}P^1$.

**My attempt:**

**Convex**

Let $0 \leq \lambda \leq 1$, $M_{a'}, M_{a''}\in S$. Since
$$\lambda(a' x + (1-a') y) + (1-\lambda) (a'' x + (1-a'') y) =\lambda b + (1-\lambda) b= b.$$
Therefore, $\lambda M_{a'} + (1-\lambda) M_{a''} \in S$. Hence, $S$ is convex.

**Bounded**

Suppose there is a metric space $(X,d)$ such that $S \subseteq X$ and $d$ is defined as the angle between two lines in radians such that
$$d(l_1,l_2)=\arctan\left(\bigg| \frac{c_2-c_1}{1+c_1 c_2} \bigg| \right),$$
where $l_1$ and $l_2$ are two lines in the plane that are not parallel to each other and has the slope of $c_1$ and $c_2$, respectively.

Then, given $M_{a'}, M_{a''} \in S$, we have

\begin{align*}
    d\left(S_1,S_2\right)&=\arctan\left(\bigg| \frac{(a''/(1-a''))-(a'/(1-a'))}{1+(a'/(1-a'))(a''/(1-a''))} \bigg|\right)\\
    &= \arctan \left(\bigg|\frac{a''-a'}{(1-a')(1-a'')+a'a''}\bigg|\right).
\end{align*}
Since $a \in (0,1)$,
$$0\leq d\left(M_{a'}, M_{a''}\right) < \frac{\pi}{2},$$
for all $M_{a'}, M_{a''} \in S$. Thus, $S$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

$S$ is not bounded. In fact, $(nb-(1-\frac 1 n) b, \frac b n) \in S$ for every $n$ since $\frac  1n (nb-(1-\frac 1 n) b)+(1-\frac  1 n) \frac b n \in S=b$. Since  $nb-(1-\frac 1 n) b \to \infty$ it follows that $S$ is unbounded.

[We don't have the liberty to choose  a suitable metric to prove boundeness. In fact any set is bounded in some metric].

Comment: Is $(nb-(1-\frac 1 n) b, \frac b n)$ still a point? If so, it is not in $S$ since each element in $S$ is a line instead of a point. I think it is unbounded if $S$ is the union of $M_a$ for all $a \in (0,1)$, where $S$ is a set of points.

Comment: What does it mean to say that a family of sets is convex? I think convexity of $S$ makes sense only if we intepret $S$ as the union of the lines $M_a: 0<a<1$.

Comment: Also, doesn't the concept of "bounded" only exist in a metric space? Without choosing a suitable metric, how do we prove a set is bounded?

Comment: Starting from the definition of a convex set: if the convex combination of sets in $S$ is in $S$, can we conclude the $S$ is convex?

Comment: As I said every set is bounded in some metric. So the question does not make sense at all.